# My code is not updating its output [API] [Python]

Tags: python, api

My code isn't updating it's output it keeps duplicating it instead.

this code is working on Python 3.7, it grabs bitcoin current price from Coindesk's API, I have put it in a while loop with a sleep function for it to update every 5 seconds, but the problem is it doesn't update the price it just keep showing the price it first received then it just duplicates it, the only way for me to get the updated price is to stop and restart the code manually every time.

```py
import requests
import os
import time

r = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')

while(not time.sleep(5)):
    os.system('cls')
    print('the current price is: $' + r.json()['bpi']['USD']['rate'])
```

how can I make it update the price every time the code is executed?

Comment: Put the get inside the loop

Comment: What did you *expect* to happen?

Comment: The problem is in your logic as you are only making the call to API at once, you need to put api call in loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to make a new request each time you want to update the value...

This would look like the following:

```
import requests
import os
import time

while(not time.sleep(5)):
    os.system('cls')
    r = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
    print('the current price is: $' + r.json()['bpi']['USD']['rate'])
```

**Although**, if you want to get fancy/maybe improve readability, you could do the following:

```
import requests
import os
import time

def coin_value():
    val = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
    val = r.json()['bpi']['USD']['rate']
    return val

while(not time.sleep(5)):
    os.system('cls')
    print('the current price is: $' + coin_value())
```

It's more lines of code, but could make things easier for everyone and anyone who reads your code in the future, especially if there is a lot more than this!

Comment: thanks you very much that was more than helpful, could you explain how the extra lines makes it more readable? i'm pretty new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your logic as you are only making the call to API at once, you need to put api call in loop

```
import requests
import os
import time


while(not time.sleep(5)):
    r = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
    os.system('cls')
    print('the current price is: $' + r.json()['bpi']['USD']['rate'])
```

The output will be like this:

```
the current price is: $10,450.6217
the current price is: $10,450.6217
the current price is: $10,450.6217
the current price is: $10,450.6217
the current price is: $10,450.6217
the current price is: $10,450.6217
the current price is: $10,450.6217
the current price is: $10,450.6217
the current price is: $10,450.6217
the current price is: $10,450.6217
the current price is: $10,450.6217
the current price is: $10,450.6217
the current price is: $10,455.7950
the current price is: $10,455.7950
the current price is: $10,455.7950
the current price is: $10,455.7950
the current price is: $10,455.7950
the current price is: $10,455.7950
the current price is: $10,455.7950
the current price is: $10,455.7950
the current price is: $10,455.7950
the current price is: $10,455.7950
the current price is: $10,455.7950
the current price is: $10,455.7950
the current price is: $10,457.9417
the current price is: $10,457.9417
the current price is: $10,457.9417
the current price is: $10,457.9417

Process finished with exit code -1
```